# Controller path for nested resource - undefined method `<controller>_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble displaying my form at /users/2/friends/new. I'm receiving

```
undefined method `friends_path' for #<#<Class:0x21f0c14>:0x21ef364>
```

Here is the beginning of the form

```
<% form_for(@friend) do |f| %>
```

And the friends controller

```
def new
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @friend = @user.friends.build
end
```

This is the route

```
resources :users do
       resources :friends
end
```

And the relevant path from "rake routes"

```
users/:user_id/friends/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"friends", :action=>"new"}
```

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. This is my first rails 3 app.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try:

```
user_friends_path(@user)
```

It's because it's a nested resource:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

**Update:**
As for the form, you can do:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @friend] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm misunderstanding about where to put the path.. When I do form_for user_friend_path(@friend) it throws up an even stranger error. All I'm trying to do is display a form to add "friends" and associate them as belonging to the user.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do.  You have to do form_for [@user, @friend]

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. That did it! Really appreciate the help as I'm just beginning. Happy Holidays to you sir.

Comment: I've been bashing my brains out trying to get this working. Many, many thanks.