# assets prefixed to url action path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, form-for

I'm using rails 3.2.2 and haml. I'm not sure why it's prefixing the assets path to this form I'm building.

Here's the code in the view:

```
%table
  %tbody
    - @netscaler.vips.each do |vip|
      %tr
        = form_for vip, :url => { :controller => 'vips', :action => 'update' }, :remote => true do |f|
          %td= f.check_box vip, { :checked => vip.active ? true : false, :class => 'vip_state' }
          %td= vip.name

%p
```

Here's the html output:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/assets?action=update&amp;controller=vips" class="edit_vip" data-remote="true" id="edit_vip_95" method="post">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
          <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
          <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="CdH+TARoORHZHhhwuPfooGdDDgZBTJjR7uRBvYdoh1I=" />
        </div>
        <td>
          <input name="vip[#&lt;Vip:0x92c384c&gt;]" type="hidden" value="0" />
          <input checked="checked" class="vip_state" id="vip_#&lt;Vip:0x92c384c&gt;" name="vip[#&lt;Vip:0x92c384c&gt;]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
         </td>
         <td>image-vip</td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm also using nested resources:

```
resources :netscalers do
  resources :vips
end
```

Comment: if you don't pass the `:url` args it's works or not ?

Comment: 1. Why not use route helper, like `vip_path(vip)`

Comment: 2. You have error in 6 line, need `%td= f.check_box :vip, ...`

Comment: You need to fix up the form itself. you have the resources right, just reference the parent object as well. ... it might clean up your logic a bit ... refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528070/308701 also your check_box syntax is wrong. it should be `f.check_box :active`