# Rails 3: save method wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm building my first Rails Application and until now everything went fine but then I found the following scenario: One Presentation is supposed to have N Iterations. I'm NOT using REST. So, I was trying to make a simple form to create iterations.

**These are the models:**

```
class Presentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :iterations
end

class Iteration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :presentation
  attr_accessible :presentation_id, :description, :delivery_date, :file
  validates :presentation_id, :presence => {:message => 'is required.'}
end
```

**These are the actions in the controller:**

```
#Shows Form
def add
  @iteration = Iteration.new
  @presentation = Presentation.find(params[:id])
end

#Saves Form
def save
  @iteration = Iteration.new(params[:iteration])
  @iteration.delivery_date = Time.now
  if @iteration.save
    flash[:notice] = "Saved succesfully!"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Changes were not saved."
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

**These would be the view in HAML:**

```
= form_for @iteration, :url => { :action => "save", :method => "post" }, :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f|

- if @iteration.errors.any?
  There were some errors:
  .notice-text.fg-color-white
    %ul.notice
    - for message in @iteration.errors.full_messages
      %li= message
%br

.field
  = f.label :description, "Description"
  = f.text_area :description, :class=>"form-text-area", :rows=>5
.field
  = f.label :file, "Upload File"
  = f.file_field :file
.field
  = hidden_field_tag :presentation_id, @presentation.id
%br
= f.submit "Save"
```

The problem is, save method wont save, but @iteration.errors.count's value on the view is 0.
I used then save! instead as I read in another post, that way it throw the following error:

Validation failed: Presentation is required.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please notice that in the view I used to have "f.hidden_field" instead of "hidden_field_tag" but I changed it for some other reasons, however I was getting the same error before that.

Comment: I've noticed none of the attributes is reaching the controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HAML,

```
hidden_field_tag :presentation_id
```

needs to be,

```
f.hidden_field :presentation_id, :value => @presentation.id
```

Comment: I did try f.hidden_field but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I tried your solution, but same error... I found out that if I do something like @iteration.presentation = Presentation.find... then it actually works. I mean, it's like the object passed by the form is never attached to any presentation =/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the your model definition you can have,

1. Nested resource: Refer to [Controller path for nested resource - undefined method `<controller>_path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527933/controller-path-for-nested-resource-undefined-method-controller-path)
2. Use Virtual attributes: Extremely useful railcasts by Ryan on this -> http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised
3. Save the presentation id in session: (This is not a clean very clean method)

On your controller, you will need to instantiate iteration on presentation so that presentation id is correctly populated.